# Lower bound on the probability of guessing the mode in a small multinomial sample

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X=\left(X_{1},...,X_{k}\right)$ be a random variable that follows
a multinomial distribution with $n$ trials and $k$ categories, with
probabilities $p_{1},...,p_{k}$ such that $p_{1}-\delta\geq p_{2}\geq...\geq p_{k}$
for some $\delta> 0$.

Let $\mathrm{mode}(X):=\left\{ i\ |\ \forall j\ X_{i}\geq X_{j}\right\} $
and $\mathrm{maj}(X)$ be the r.v. such that
$$
\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=i)=\frac{1\!\!1_{\left\{ i\in\mathrm{mode}(X)\right\} }}{\left|\mathrm{mode}(X)\right|}
$$
i.e. $\mathrm{maj}(X)$ is the most frequent value in the realization of $X$
(breaking ties uniformly at random).

I'm interested in lower bounding $\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=1)-\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=2)$. 
For $n\in \Omega(\delta^{-2})$ we can use the Chernoff bound and for $n\in \Theta(\delta^{-2})$ we can use the Berry-Esseen inequality. 
But what can be said when $n\in o(\delta^{-2})$?

Some people told me I should find such estimates somewhere, but nobody could point out a reference. This is what I got so far.

Using the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) that the cumulative distribution of the binomial can be expressed in terms of the regularized incomplete beta function, I'm able to prove the following.

**Lemma.**
For $k=2$ it holds 
$$
\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=1)-\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=2)\geq\sqrt{\frac{2n-2}{\pi}}\delta\left(1-\delta^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}
$$

From the previous lemma, I can prove, inductively, a lower bound for
general $k$ at the price of a multiplicative factor $e^{-c\left(k-2\right)}$ for some constant $c>0$:
$$
\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=1)-\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=2)\geq \sqrt{\frac{2n-2}{\pi}}\frac{\delta\left(1-\delta^{2}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}}{e^{\left(k-2\right)c}}
$$

I don't think $\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=1)-\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=2)$ decays exponentially in $k$.

So, do anybody have a reference or some better bounds for the following?

**Question.**
Give a good lower bound on $\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=1)-\Pr(\mathrm{maj}(X)=2)$ when $n\in o(\delta^{-2})$.